# MapView marker show previous on iOS

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

With Firemonkey 10.4.2.

I had a problem when I click on marker.
If I do that

- Click on Marker A
- Click on Marker B
- Click on Map
- Click on Marker A => I see info of Marker B, the MapMarker of MapViewMarkerClick is bad

I find a problem on FMX.Maps.iOS the last Marker is keep in memory and never set to nil, that's why I always have the same. When you click on a marker, it's look like you go to MapClick and then MapMarkerClick. That's not really clear.

When the map is shown with all marker. If click on Marker A, I first go to MapClick, I need to click a second time on the Marker to see it. Then I can naviguate to each marker, but if I click on map. The next time I click on marker I need to do it 2x.

All is good on Android, I think it's a problem in FMX.Maps.iOS again.

Any idea ?

Here is the original code with my edit :

```
procedure TMapKitMapView.MapEvent(const Event: TMapEvent);
// added
var
  SelectedMarker: TMapMarker;
// end added
begin
// added
  SelectedMarker := FSelectedMarker;
// end added

  case Event.Kind of
    TMapEventKind.CameraChanged:
      begin
        SyncCameraPosition;
        FHostControl.DoCameraChanged;
      end;
    TMapEventKind.MarkerClick:
      begin
        // Marker has been selected
        FSelectedMarker := Event.Marker;
        FHostControl.DoMarkerClick(Event.Marker);
      end;
    TMapEventKind.MarkerDeselect:
        FSelectedMarker := nil;
    TMapEventKind.MarkerDragStart:
      FHostControl.DoMarkerDragStart(Event.Marker);
    TMapEventKind.MarkerDrag:
      FHostControl.DoMarkerDrag(Event.Marker);
    TMapEventKind.MarkerDragEnd:
      FHostControl.DoMarkerDragEnd(Event.Marker);
    TMapEventKind.MapClick:
      if FDragState = MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone then
        if FSelectedMarker = nil then
          FHostControl.DoMapClick(Event.LatLng)
        else
          FHostControl.DoMarkerClick(FSelectedMarker);
    TMapEventKind.MapLongClick:
      if FDragState = MKAnnotationViewDragStateNone then
        if FSelectedMarker = nil then
          FHostControl.DoMapLongClick(Event.LatLng);
    TMapEventKind.MapDoubleClick:
      if FSelectedMarker = nil then
        FHostControl.DoMapDoubleClick(Event.LatLng)
      else
        FHostControl.DoMarkerDoubleClick(FSelectedMarker);
  end;

// added
  if FSelectedMarker = SelectedMarker then
    FSelectedMarker := nil;
// end added
end;
```

Comment: You should show your code that you're using that reproduces the behaviour, rather than what code you're using to try and "fix" it. This example works fine for me, using the steps you described: https://gist.github.com/DelphiWorlds/2e65ad9998a017351778ad2f321fdbd1

Comment: That's not really same but when you clic on marker B and then you click on the map, you didn't go to MapClick, you need to click 2 times to go on the MapClick method. I create a gist here : https://gist.github.com/retwas/79882350bcedd1fdc605ae7bb522f50c

Comment: Why did you create a gist? Just update your question with the code you are using

Comment: Regardless of my last comment, I am still not seeing the behaviour you describe. For the last tap in your steps (tap marker A) I see the info for marker A. I do see that OnMarkerClick fires when tapping the map while the last marker's callout is showing - as far as I can tell that should not happen, but it's not what you describe

Comment: II've also added a comment to my gist: https://gist.github.com/DelphiWorlds/2e65ad9998a017351778ad2f321fdbd1#gistcomment-3730276